# Procedural lines/scrabbles

Tags: texturing

In order to make procedural scratches texture, I wanted to make some random lines scrabbles like on picture (scratches might be more accurate name but it reminds me of just random scrabbles).

Is that possible, if yes, how?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Randomness is one of the hardest thing to achieve. Messing up the coordinates of simple textures might help.

You can try using a checker texture, separate the texture coordinates of one axis of the mapping, and use a wave texture to create distorted lines. Then mix that with another texture to darken some of the lines.

[image]

(click on the image to enlarge)

Then mix that that with other groups of nodes that go in different axes and with different kind of distortions and use other control (or mask) the mix

[image]

(click on the image to enlarge)

NOTE: this kinds of setups can get very complex and cumbersome, so it might be easier to pack things in node groups. Also to understand how things are working start with the checker texture only, then add texture coordinates and a separate XYZ to see the result. Then add nodes one by one to understand what each one is doing and how changing size, distortion, detail etc, are affecting the result. There are infinite ways to combine textures, coordinates and mappings and effects. Trial and error will require some time before you find something that works for you.

Comment: Ah yes, I know a lot of stuff can be done with vector manipulation but I just can't get myself to understand it. This example you made should work just fine. I just wanted to make it be able to be on any object without UV mapping it and I think I did it with plugging object texture coordinates in wave and musgrave inputs and left UV coordinates for separate xyz. Now one thing that is bothering me why I had to use texture instead of point type in vector mapping node I can't figure it out since when I use point it is all black..?

Comment: Again, this is one example, you don't necessarily have to use UVs and can manipulate texture mapping using whatever settings you want. The point I'm trying to make is that is that randomness is hard to achieve procedurally, for what you want to do you need some form of distortion, lots of masks with noise textures, and lots of patience. This answer I hope will encourage users to play with many variables and not to expect results with a simple click.

Comment: As for the question on point vs texture. It would be better if you ask as a separate post, to keep things orgainzed.

Comment: Well I tried using object and generated coordinates for node that separates xyz and it doesn't work, anyhow I will try to experiment, I got some results with musgrave textures where  one is slightly shifted and then use difference however it has some artifacts.
I will post that as separate question but I will first try and see what google says. Thanks!

Comment: Again... start with a single node, play with it and understand what it is doing, then add second node and play with it, if you compound multiple variables all at once it can get very confusing very quickly.